# php and mysql php myadmin database

Tags: php, html, mysql, email

In PHP MyAdmin I get this:

---

1.EMAIL     |     NAME

2."NAME"

3."EMAIL"

4."NAME"

5."EMAIL"

6."NAME"

7."EMAIL"

I want NAME to go to NAME column and EMAIL to go to EMAIL one.

Below is the code:

```
if($_POST['action']=="sub"){
    conndb($servername,$username,$password);
    namecheck($name);
    mailcheck($email);


    if (((empty($name)) || (empty($email))) || ((empty($name)) && (empty($email)))){
      echo "<p><strong>You have to fill the fields!</strong></p>";
    }
    else if ((mysqli_num_rows($name_result) < 1) && ( mysqli_num_rows ($email_result) < 1 )){
        $name_query="insert into stoixeia values (' ','$name')";
        mysqli_query($conn,$name_query) or die(mysql_error()) ;
        $email_query="insert into stoixeia values (' ','$email')";
        mysqli_query($conn,$email_query) or die(mysql_error()) ;
        echo "<p>Thank you for signing up!</p>";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "<p>You are already subscribed!</p>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do one `INSERT` statement, and specify which variables go in which column.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO stoixea (name, email) VALUES ('$name', '$email')";
mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
```

Also, you can't use `mysql_error()` if you're using `mysqli`, you have to use `mysqli_error()`.

It would be best if you learned how to do prepared queries instead of substituting variables in the SQL. There are many tutorials, google it.

Comment: thank you very much.
i am new to php and mysql it is for my college exams.
it worked great.
thank you again

Comment: @njazi click on the green tick to the left of the answer if it helped you.